# Meteor Server-Side HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm having some issues with a small meteor app I'm trying to build. I have a feeling its a result of not fully understanding how the server-client relationship works. I've tried to get it working for hours, and see this as the only logical way to set it up. It might help to add that I am a beginner.

It is also worth noting that I had it running fine while making the http request on the client side.

What is supposed to happen:

A form is submitted, the text from the form is sent to an API via an http request, JSON is returned, parsed, and a value is returned back to the user (they give a country code, it returns a border). Along with this, I wanted to store each request in a collection with a timestamp.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is JS:

```
borders = new Mongo.Collection("borders");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client

  //set the session blank before submit action on form. 

  Template.hello.helpers({
    borders: function () {
      // return borders.find({});
      // return borders.find({}, {limit: 1});
      return Session.get("border");
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      // Prevent default browser form submit
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get value from form element
      var countryCode = event.target.text.value;

      //set form element variable in the session so it can be accessed on the server
      session.set(countryCode)

      //invoke the server method
      Meteor.call("getID", function(error, results) {
        console.log(results.content); //results.data should be a JSON object
      });

    }
  });
}

//server-side code 
if (Meteor.isServer) {
      session.get(countryCode)
      var url = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/"+countryCode;
    Meteor.methods({
        getID: function () {
          this.unblock();
          HTTP.get(url, {timeout:30000}, function(error, response) {
            var respJson = JSON.parse(response.content);
            console.log(respJson)
            Session.set("border",respJson["subregion"])
            // Insert a task into the collection
            borders.insert({
              text: respJson["borders"],
              createdAt: new Date() // current time
            });
            // Clear form
            event.target.text.value = "";
          });
        }
    });
}
```

Error I get when the app is run:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20151203-17:09:54.345(-8)? (STDERR)          
W20151203-17:09:54.346(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1evms9b++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: session is not defined
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR)     at borderApp.js:38:7
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/Dev/Web/borderApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/borderApp.js:67:4
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/Dev/Web/borderApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1evms9b++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20151203-17:09:54.347(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/Dev/Web/borderApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

This is the HTML I am using for the front end:

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>

      <form class="new-task">
        <input class="input-lg form-control" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
      </form>
    </header>

<H3>
{{> hello}}
</h3>

  </div>
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <p>{{borders}}</p>
</template>

<template name="button">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Find Borders &rarr;</button>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you get the error because you wrote session.set(varhere) instead of Session.set('nameofsessionvar',newvalueforsessionvar). However, even then it would not work because the Session variables are globally available to the client on a per client basis, not the server.

Try changing:

```
//session.set(countryCode)
Meteor.call("getID", countryCode, function(error, results) {
...
}
```

and:

```
//session.get(countryCode)
//var url = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/"+countryCode;
getID: function (countrycode) {
      var url = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/"+countryCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may misunderstand `Session` of `Meteor` with different framework. In `Meteor`, `Session` is only available in client, not in server, please refer to: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session

For your problem, you can pass countryCode as a parameter for `Meteor.call`

```
  Meteor.call("getID", countryCode, function(error, results) {
    console.log(results.content); //results.data should be a JSON object
  });
```

And your server:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        getID: function (countryCode) {
        var url = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/alpha/"+countryCode;
          this.unblock();
          HTTP.get(url, {timeout:30000}, function(error, response) {
            var respJson = JSON.parse(response.content);
            console.log(respJson)

            // Insert a task into the collection
            borders.insert({
              text: respJson["borders"],
              createdAt: new Date() // current time
            });
            // Clear form
            event.target.text.value = "";
          });
        }
    });
}
```